# How can I create a grouped bar plot visualisation in R using the given dataset

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

How to create a grouped bar plot for the following dataset in R

I'm using this dataset:

```
full_trains <- readr::read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2019/2019-02-26/full_trains.csv")
```

I wanted to find the Wthe highest, lowest, and average departure delay time for each year. Here's the script for that and data output [(attached)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8uMm.png)

```
Summary_statistics <- full_trains %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  summarise(min_ave_time = min(journey_time_avg),
            max_ave_time = max(journey_time_avg),
            mean_ave_time = mean(journey_time_avg)) %>%
            ungroup()
```

Can someone please help me create a visualisation for this data output similar to [image: what I could create in Excel]?

Comment: What do you exactly mean is not clear, you want separate histograms for min/max/mean avg? histogram is mainly to show variable count or frequency, what are you trying to show?

Comment: You're right. I've just updated my question and added an image. If I use Excel, I'll be able to create the attached visualisation, i.e., min, max, and mean for each year. I'm trying to recreate a similar visualisation in R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With ggplot2 you can mimic your desired excel version; adjust argument values to suit your desired design.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

Summary_statistics <- 
  full_trains  |> 
  group_by(year)  |> 
  summarise(min_ave_time = min(journey_time_avg),
            max_ave_time = max(journey_time_avg),
            mean_ave_time = mean(journey_time_avg)) |> 
  ungroup() |> 
  pivot_longer(-year, names_to = "var", values_to = "avg_time") 


ggplot(Summary_statistics, aes(year, avg_time, fill = var)) + 
  geom_col(position = position_dodge2(width = 0.8)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = round(avg_time, 1)), 
            vjust = -0.3, 
            position = position_dodge2(width = 0.9)) +
  labs(x = NULL,
       y = NULL,
       fill = NULL) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",
        panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_blank())
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-05-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I'm a big fan of the **Rnvd3** package for such charts because of the interactivity it offers. In particular the grouped/stacked effect is really funny.

```r
library(Rnvd3)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

full_trains <- readr::read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2019/2019-02-26/full_trains.csv")

Summary_statistics <- full_trains %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  summarise(min_ave_time = min(journey_time_avg),
            max_ave_time = max(journey_time_avg),
            mean_ave_time = mean(journey_time_avg)) %>%
  ungroup()

dat <- Summary_statistics %>% 
  pivot_longer(-year, names_to = "variable", values_to = "average_time") 


multiBarChart(
  data = dat, 
  average_time ~ year,
  by = "variable",
  height = "500px"
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Does this answer your question?

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

full_trains <- readr::read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2019/2019-02-26/full_trains.csv")

full_trains %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = journey_time_avg)) + 
    geom_histogram() + 
    facet_wrap(~year)
```

[image: Histogram]

Answer (score 0):

What you are referring to is a "grouped bar plot" and not "histogram". To do it in R you first need to transform your table into long format (using `pivot_longer()` in tidyverse or other options like `reshape2::melt()`. Then feed this into a ggplot item with `geom_bar()`, you have to set `stat = "identity"` and `position = position_dodge()` to get the exact type of grouped bar plot that you want:

```
library(dplyr)

Summary_statistics %>% 
  pivot_longer(-year, names_to = "variable", values_to = "average_time") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = year, y = average_time, fill = variable)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge())
```

output:
[image]